# jQuery automatic add two numbers from text fields

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add two numbers whenever a keyup happens in the textboxes of those two numbers. I want it to use jquery so my addition code is these:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>jQuery live Try</h1>
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number 1" class="num1 key">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number 2" class="num2 key">
    <br><br>
    Sum: <input type="text" class="sum" readonly="readonly"><br><br><br>
</form>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sum").val("0");
        $(".key").val("");

        function calc(){
        var $num1=$(".num1").val();
        var $num2=$(".num2").val();
        $(".sum").val($num1+$num2);
    }
    $(".key").keyup(function(){
        calc();
    });
});
```

But if i enter 1 and 2 it outputs 12 not 3. How can I make it output the sum?

[The js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blaisemugisha/qsnygcwg/)

Comment: `$(".sum").val(+$num1+$num2);`

Comment: sorry but doesn't work

Comment: Strange, I don't know why that doesn't work, but this does : http://jsfiddle.net/qsnygcwg/5/

Comment: i can see now your fiddle works. i first added the + before val(+$num1+$num2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `parseInt()` to convert `string` to `Number`

```
function calc() {
    var $num1 = ($(".num1").val() != "" && !isNaN($(".num1").val())) ? parseInt($(".num1").val()) : 0;
    var $num2 = ($(".num2").val() != "" && !isNaN($(".num2").val())) ? parseInt($(".num2").val()) : 0;
    $(".sum").val($num1 + $num2);
}
```

**Your overall code should look like this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sum").val("0");
    $(".key").val("");

    function calc() {

        var $num1 = ($.trim($(".num1").val()) != "" && !isNaN($(".num1").val())) ? parseInt($(".num1").val()) : 0;
        console.log($num1);
        var $num2 = ($.trim($(".num2").val()) != "" && !isNaN($(".num2").val())) ? parseInt($(".num2").val()) : 0;
        console.log($num2);
        $(".sum").val($num1 + $num2);
    }
    $(".key").keyup(function() {
        calc();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h1>jQuery live Try</h1>
 <form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Number 1" class="num1 key">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Number 2" class="num2 key">
  <br><br>
  Sum: <input type="text" class="sum" readonly="readonly"><br><br><br>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect. thank you. but what happens if the textbox is empty? according to your conditional operator

Comment: If it's empty or `NOT A NUMBER` its value will be considered as a `0`.

Comment: @BlaiseM. have also used `$.trim()` value incase of `white-space`

Comment: okay! now i can see: If num1 is not empty then parse int rather send 0

Comment: @BlaiseM. Sorry I didn't get your last comment.

Comment: I was just explaining the way i understood your conditional operator. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the `.val()` method return a `string`, `string 1 + string 2 = 12`.
So use the `parseFloat` method.

**change**

```
var $num1=$(".num1").val();
var $num2=$(".num2").val();
```

**to**

```
var $num1=parseFloat($(".num1").val());
var $num2=parseFloat($(".num2").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from jQuery is a `string` so you have to cast your value into `integers`:

```
var $num1=parseInt($(".num1").val(), 10) || 0;
var $num2=parseInt($(".num2").val(), 10) || 0;
$(".sum").val($num1+$num2);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u82hd7th/2/)

or use `parseFloat()` if you want to support `floating numbers`.

Another possibilty would be to use the `Number()`-function, as this will cast an empty string automatically:

```
var $num1=Number($(".num1").val());
var $num2=Number($(".num2").val());
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rLofc270/1/)

**Reference**

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

[Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: Your demo shows `NaN`, as there's not check for blank values.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the string representation to Integer

```
var $num1=parseInt($(".num1").val());
var $num2=parseInt($(".num2").val());
```

Comment: Side note: [Always specify a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters)