# Iterative addition in php

Tags: php, dreamweaver

i created a textbox in a php page, the user would enter the a no in it. which will bring textboxes that corresponds to the no the user entered. the user will be prompted to enter values into the textboxes, will be finally summed up. How can dis addition be done.?

Comment: use append function in jQuery. It may help you to do that work

Comment: PHP is a server side language which mean all you code runs on server, what you want is to react to user input which can be done on client-side language such as javascript by generating/cloning the textboxes on runtime

Comment: yes, i was able to achieve the cloning of textboxes on runtime with a loop in php, but the addition is my problem now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233886/jquery-automatic-add-two-numbers-from-text-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following to create your textboxes:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
    $count = array_sum($_POST['new-input']);
    echo $count;
} else if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {
    $totalBoxes = isset($_POST['boxes']) ? $_POST['boxes'] : 1;
}

?>

<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($totalBoxes)): ?>
    <?php foreach (range(1, $totalBoxes) as $inputCount): ?>
        <form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="new-input[<?= $inputCount; ?>]" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate!" />
        </form>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <label>Amount of boxes</label>
        <input type="text" name="boxes" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="generate" value="Generate" />
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```